# IE remove 4 hours form date when convert string to date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, date

I have angular app it work fine with chrome but I have small bugs in IE one of them is date object is not convert it right date time ? on chrome it convet string '2015-04-09T12:30:00' to 'Thu Apr 09 2015 08:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)' but IE convert it to 'Thu Apr 09 2015 12:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'just want to know why and how to fix it ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/SBXzQe6oArXA8w3swfMo

javascript

```
//this line work fine in google chrome 
    $scope.tm = new Date(user.until);
```

Comment: it is '2015-04-09T12:30:00'

Comment: So the conversion of IE looks ok but Chrome remove 4 hours.

Comment: no chrome ok but IE wrong

Comment: Firefox return for me `Thu Apr 09 2015 12:30:00 GMT+0200` this is the same that IE.

Comment: Hi I created plunker to  show what is problem just I want to make them as chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's your problem:
[ECMAScript ed 6 draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format)

ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support

> The date time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and time) can be passed and parsed. The UTC time zone is used to interpret arguments in ISO 8601 format that do not contain time zone information (**note that ECMAScript ed 6 draft specifies that date time strings without a time zone are to be treated as local, not UTC**).

Let's compare ISO times in IE and Chrome.

Chrome: "2015-04-09T12:30:00.000Z"

IE: "2015-04-09T09:30:00.000Z"

IE assumes the ISO time is local time, like it should be.
Chrome actually assumes its UTC.